# Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore. dotnet publish

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, publish, dotnet-cli, dotnet-publish

I am getting this message when I executed the dotnet publish command on cmd.

"Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore."

```
dotnet publish "/p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\PMIAdmin.pubxml"
```

[image]

It is working when I clicked the publish button on Visual Studio 2019

[image]

How can I publish this project from cmd?

dotnet version: .NET Framework 4.5
project type: Asp.Net MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet publish` is for .NET Core, to publish .NET Framework app you can use MSBuild directly. For example from Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt:

```
msbuild path_to_sln_file /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<profile-name>
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment).